# saving of entity in the database causes unexpected behaviors

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

When I try persist the entity below in the database, in a application which uses spring and hibernate, in the way it's presented, I get the error `object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing`; but if I add the value `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` to the annotation @OneToOne (or add the annotation @Cascade), for each attribute I don't fill it's inserted an empty record in the database.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cliente")
public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="usuario")
    @Order(value=1)
    private Usuario usuario;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="pessoa_fisica")
    @Order(value=2)
    private PessoaFisica pessoaFisica;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="pessoa_juridica")
    @Order(value=3)
    private PessoaJuridica pessoaJuridica;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="endereco_entrega")
    @Order(value=4)
    private Endereco endereco_entrega;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="endereco_cobranca")
    @Order(value=5)
    private Endereco endereco_cobranca;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name="pedidos_do_cliente", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_cliente")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_pedido")})
    @Order(value=6)
    private List<Pedido> pedido;
}
```

Anyone can tell me how to fix this problem?

ps.: below the related method which handle this process:

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="cadastra", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String cadastra(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result, @RequestParam(value="file", required=false) MultipartFile file, @RequestParam(value="icone", required=false) MultipartFile icone) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, IOException {
    serv.cadastra(object);
    serv.upload_picture(object, file, "picture");
    serv.upload_picture(object, icone, "icone");
    return "";
}
```

**service**

```
@Transactional
public void cadastra(E e) {
    dao.persist(e);
}
```

**dao class**

```
@Transactional
public void persist(E transientInstance) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(transientInstance);
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
CREATE TABLE cliente
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  endereco_cobranca integer,
  endereco_entrega integer,
  pessoa_fisica integer,
  pessoa_juridica integer,
  usuario integer,
  CONSTRAINT cliente_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_4taj5h8hxci6slrw0n3d336i7 FOREIGN KEY (endereco_entrega)
      REFERENCES endereco (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_7a5l0l5enj00apelvmcdatkmm FOREIGN KEY (pessoa_juridica)
      REFERENCES pessoa_juridica (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_iiibo76b56caciax4yl0jo0m6 FOREIGN KEY (pessoa_fisica)
      REFERENCES pessoa_fisica (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_lwavy2v0wb0vmxisg7hbe3mbu FOREIGN KEY (usuario)
      REFERENCES usuario (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_r2pyppeltv7xoe5quenf2l1gd FOREIGN KEY (endereco_cobranca)
      REFERENCES endereco (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE cliente
  OWNER TO klebermo;
```

Comment: could you post your database structure

Answer (score 0):

In your view layer, are you creating new objects for the these linked columns? or in the controller that serves the form, are you adding 'new' objects to the model? It seems as though you have created empty java objects for these one-to-one columns which is why you cant save the parent without saving the children and why with cascade option it creates empty records.

Comment: but how I could solve this, for avoid create this empty records? (I posted the related methods above - from controller, service and dao classes)

Comment: can you pass null values from your view layer for the objects that should be null instead of passing new empty objects? worst case, check if the objects are effectively empty in your service layer and set them to null if you dont want to create an empty record for them. enable the cascading btw.

Comment: but I am passing null values from my view.  that's the problem: I pass null, but the application is saving an empty record.